What useful project can I make with involutive meadows for school?
Well, I don’t understand how is it possible that 1/0=0 as well as my teacher of high school. So what practical real useful project can u advise me connecting with involutive meadows in computer science with some applications, and may u explain how is it possible 1/0=0?

(This term seems uncommon outside Russian literature - can you point to an introduction easy to grasp?)

it’s not a russian literature. check this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.01284
